# How is Elem working with a single element

Tags: haskell

The problem is to pack consecutive duplicates of list elements into sublists.
I do not understand how `elem` is working with a single element here,

For Example,

```
pack [1,1,2,2,3,4]
```

Then `x` will be 1 and `(head (pack xs))` will be 1.
How can:

```
1 `elem`  1
```

work when `elem` is of type `a -> [a] -> Bool`?

Also, please explain the recursion.

```
pack :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [[a]]
pack [] = []
pack [x] = [[x]]
pack (x:xs) = if x `elem` (head (pack xs))
              then (x:(head (pack xs))):(tail (pack xs))
              else [x]:(pack xs)
```

Comment: `(head (pack xs))` will be `[1]`, not `1`. Then, it makes sense to check ``1 `elem` [1]``.

Comment: But, head always returns a single element then how will it return [1] in this case ?

Comment: @Arushi That single element can be a list (if the input is a list of lists).

Comment: This is a paragon example of how `head,tail` can produce code which is 1) hard to read and 2) hard to evaluate (can you state its complexity? how long it takes to check that there will be no runtime errors?). Using a simple `case` and pattern matching would greatly improve it, IMO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your example, `x` will be 1, but `head (pack xs)` is *not* 1.  In fact, you can see from it's type signature that the type of `pack xs` must be `[[Int]]` (or at least `[[a]]` for some kind of number `a`) namely a list *of lists* of numbers, so `head (pack xs)` has type `[Int]`, not type `Int`.  Whatever its value is, it can't be `1`.

If that's still not clear, look at the shorter example `pack [1,2]`.  It will match the pattern `pack (x:xs)` with `x=1` and `xs=[2]`, so the right side of the `elem` call will be `head (pack [2])`.  You can verify that this is equivalent to `head [[2]]` which evaluates to `[2]`, and now the expression:

```
1 `elem` [2]
```

makes perfect sense.

Remember, even though `head` returns the first element of a  list, Haskell allows lists of lists, and the first element of a list of lists is another list.

**Edit:  To explain the recursion,** let's go through a full example of `pack [1,1,2]` in detail.  Every time we try to evaluate a `pack` call, we'll use one of the patterns for `pack` which I've numbered:

```
pack [] = []               -- #1
pack [x] = [[x]]           -- #2
pack (x:xs) = if x `elem` (head (pack xs))    -- #3
              then (x:(head (pack xs))):(tail (pack xs))
              else [x]:(pack xs)
```

When Haskell tries to evaluate `pack [1,1,2]`, because `[1,1,2]` is equivalent to `1:[1,2]` (if you don't see why, look up the definition of the `:` operator and try it out on a few examples!), it matches pattern #3 with `x=1` and `xs=[1,2]`.  So, Haskell can evaluate this using the right hand side of pattern #3 with these substituted values for `x` and `xs`.  Just to be totally clear, the RHS with those substitutions looks like the following, which we'll call "expression (A)":

```
if 1 `elem` (head (pack [1,2]))
then (1:(head (pack [1,2]))):(tail (pack [1,2]))
else [1]:(pack [1,2])
```

Make sure you believe this is right before continuing!  Now, the hardest part of evaluating this expression is figuring out how to evaluate `pack [1,2]`, which is used in several places.  So, let's figure out how Haskell evaluates `pack [1,2]`.  Again, because `[1,2]` is equivalent to `1:[2]` (check it!), this matches pattern #3 with `x=1` and `xs=[2]`.  The RHS of pattern #3 with these substitutions is the following, which we'll call "expression (B)":

```
if 1 `elem` (head (pack [2]))
then (1:(head (pack [2]))):(tail (pack [2]))
else [1]:(pack [2])
```

To evaluate expression (B), we need to figure out the value of `pack [2]`.  This time, this expression matches pattern #2 with `x=2`.  (Actually, it would match pattern #3, too, with `x=2` and `xs=[]` but Haskell uses the first pattern that matches, so it never considers this possibility.)  Substituting `x=2` into the RHS of pattern #2 we get the following equivalent value for `pack [2]`, which we'll call "expression (C)", even though it's so short it probably doesn't deserve a name.

```
[[2]]
```

Taking this and substituting it back into expression (B) above, we literally get:

```
if 1 `elem` (head [[2]])
then (1:(head [[2]])):(tail [[2]])
else [1]:[[2]]
```

All I've done here is replaced `pack [2]` with `[[2]]` everywhere it appears, and then I removed some extra parentheses that didn't change the meaning.  The condition in the `if` statement is the same as `` 1 `elem` [2] ``, which is false, so the value is `[1]:[[2]]` which can be rewritten as `[[1],[2]]`.  (Again, check if you don't see why.)  This, then is the final value for expression (B) and so the final value of `pack [1,2]`.  Now, we can substitute this value into expression (A) to get:

```
if 1 `elem` (head [[1],[2]])
then (1:(head [[1],[2]])):(tail [[1],[2]])
else [1]:[[1],[2]]
```

Now, because `head [[1],[2]]` is just `[1]`, the condition in the `if` statement is `` 1 `elem` [1] `` which is true, so Haskell evaluates the part given by the `then` clause.  This is ugly, but you should be able to convince yourself that it's value is:

```
(1:(head [[1],[2]])):(tail [[1],[2]])
= (1:[1]):[[2]]
= [1,1]:[[2]]
= [[1,1],[2]]
```

This is the final value of expression (A), but of course that was the value of `pack [1,1,2]`, so you can see that it all worked out.

Comment: That means if I take an input `pack [1,1,2,2,3,4]` then x is 1 and Haskell converts the list to **[[1,1,2,2,3,4]]** , takes out its head which is **[1,1,2,2,3,4]**. Please explain the recursion as well with the same example. Thank you

Comment: @Arushi No, Haskell does not wrap the list, `pack` does. When `x` is 1 we have that `xs` is `[1,2,2,3,4]` and pack is called on that, returning `[[1],[2,2],[3],[4]]` whose head is `[1]` and tail `[[2,2],[3],[4]`.

Comment: Is there any simple way of doing this using pattern matching and not using `elem` ? @K. A. Buhr

Comment: Yes, but you should probably post that as a separate question, since it's getting off-topic from the original.  Asking and answering questions in the comments makes it harder for others to benefit from the answer in the future.

Answer (score 1):

As chi already commented, using `head` and `tail` is generally problematic and obscuring. In your example it also creates a gigantic performance problem, since in each recursion step you evaluate `pack xs` over and over again – unless the compiler steps in with some nontrivial optimisation, this has exponential complexity!

I'd recommend the following instead, using `case` and guards:

```
pack (x:xs) = case pack xs of
   thisPack : packs
     | x `elem` thisPack -> (x:thisPack) : packs
   otherPacks            -> [x] : otherPacks
```

Comment: `head` and `tail` are not responsible for this complexity problem; the failure to pull out an expensive common subexpression is to blame. They certainly do make the code much harder to understand, however. They also may slow down the code by a constant factor by introducing excessive laziness.